# Set width and height of uploaded image

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

Can anyone pleas tell me how to resize the upload to image to a specific width and height (800*600). Then create the thumbnail of (400*300) and save thumbnails to a folder

Comment: Wait, what? Start with learning how to use a php imaging library, something like `GD`.

Comment: Re sizing an image to make it bigger isn't very good (unless it's a vector or something similar, I just assume you mean a `jpg` or something) as it will become all grainy and pixelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: the file path must exist
Using [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

```
// File from upload form
$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
// path to save image ex. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/upload/';
$targetPath = PATH_TO_FINAL_IMAGE_FOLDER;
// Grab image info
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
// Any file name will work keeping extension or just use $_FILES['file']['name']
$newName = MY_FILE_NAME.".".$fileParts['extension'];
// File path and file
$targetFile = $targetPath.$newName
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
// Resize Imagemagick only
// New file (any valid extenstion and any name)
$resizedFile = $targetPath."NEW_NAME.png";
// Using Imagemagick to change image ONLY if bigger then desired size
exec('convert "'.$targetFile.'[0]" -flatten -monitor -colorspace RGB -resize "800x600>" "'.$resizedFile.'"');
// Thumb file
$resizedFile = $targetPath."/thumb/NEW_NAME.png";
// create thumb
exec('convert "'.$targetFile.'[0]" -flatten -monitor -colorspace RGB -resize "400x300>" "'.$thumb.'"');
```

// Resize using GD

Using GD you can use:

```
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("PATH_TO_FILE");
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor("NEW_WIDTH", "NEW_HEIGHT");
imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, "NEW_WIDTH", "NEW_HEIGHT", "START_WIDTH", "START_HEIGHT");
```

[imagecreatefromjpeg](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg)

[imagecreatetruecolor](https://www.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor)

[imagecopyresampled](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled)

Comment: does it can convert png and gif too?? and how can i set the output folder??

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to change image type and set image folder using imagemagick

Comment: when i run the code. what i got it this 

" "'.$resizedFile.'"'); // Thumb file $resizedFile = $targetPath."/thumb/NEW_NAME.png"; // create thumb exec('convert "'.$targetFile.'[0]" -flatten -monitor -colorspace RGB -resize "400x300>" "'.$thumb.'"'); ?>

Comment: what is that? how can i install it?